# how to access memory pages in Linux kernel space by using pointer

Tags: memory-management, linux-kernel

In 32 bit system, each page size is 4KB. Let assume that, first page address is assigned to a pointer, how you increment the pointer to access 2nd page ? it means every pointer increment should point to the next page.

Any suggestions ??

Answer (score 1):

> Let assume that, first page address is assigned to a pointer, how you increment the pointer to access 2nd page ?

Actually you even may don't know page size. You can use `PAGE_SIZE` macro, and just:

```
ptr + PAGE_SIZE
```

should give the address of the next page if you are sure that a next page exists.

Comment: Thank you @0xAX, is it possible to access pages from userspace directly ?? if yes, how ??

Comment: What did you mean under: access a page? You already manipulation with virtual addresses which are located in memory pages when you are doing something with pointers.